# Vehicle tests, riggers and hotsimming

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

Vehicle mounted weapons  are operated with the following test for manual use:

> Weapon Skill + Agility[Accuracy]

and for remote usage it changes to:

> Gunnery + Logic[Accuracy]

Based on this, are there any changes to the way vehicle tests are made when I am hot simming in as a rigger?

The basic test for normal use is give as:

> Vehicle Skill + Reaction [Handling]

but I see nothing in the rules that this changes when hotsimming.

**Does Reaction get swapped out for a more appropriate attribute when hotsimming or does it stay the same? Given that I've pumped a lot of my attribute points into Intuition and Logic, I would prefer it if it did.**

Comment: As far as I see Hot-Sim (vs. Cold-Sim) just gives you an additional D6 initiative plus +1 dice pool modifier on Vehicle tests (and all other Matrix tests). The *big* bonus you get is probably the -1 threshold on Vehicle tests for each level of your control rig. (Not writing an answer, as I have no experience playing/GMing riggers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you treat Vehicle actions as Matrix actions while jumped in, so hot-sim gives you +1 dice pool bonus and +3d6 initiative dice as usual (page 266).

Second, you get reduction for each threshold equal to the Control Rig rank (page 199).

Third, I cannot find anything specific about weapons mounted on a jumped-in vehicle (as in, there is not any info on that in the core book), but Logic + Gunnery seems appropriate (since it is still remote operation of sorts), with +1 bonus for hot sim.